# How to make this kind of text UI?

Tags: user-interface, text

[image: this]

Comment: Longing for the good ol' days, eh? ;)

Comment: http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Fire your graphic designers :)

Comment: The colours are magnificent. Like somebody had mint ice cream and barfed it onto a curses-looking mold. Or perhaps like a printer that has run out of magenta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a text UI library. The Curses library used to be a popular option, but it is limited by copyrights.

Fortunately, there is an [uncopyrighted version](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) available.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the "Console" mode.

Depending on your development environment and language of choice, it can be as simple as Ctrl+Shift+N, "Console Project" (in Visual Studio), or tweaking compiler flags (for C++). Every IDE/language provide a way to do this.

In Windows, the Console operates in two ways. Firstly, any project can create, attach to, and modify any number of console windows whenever it wants. Secondly, with a special flag in the EXE, the project will start up already attached to a console.

The latter operates subtly differently from the former. If you want a "normal" console application, I strongly suggest *against* creating and attaching to consoles. Just use the Console mode compiler setting.

Comment: Apologies if you were really asking about a text widget library, it wasn't entirely clear :)

Answer (score 1):

[Clipper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipper_%28programming_language%29) was a popular way to do this in DOS.

Comment: @romkyns, he asked for an API to do a text interface; Clipper is one of them. If you know a better API, then that is cool, please share. But down voting my answer just because you know a better API is a bit lame. It wasn't completely clear whether he wanted a modern API or if he wanted to know about legacy APIs, that's why I mentioned Clipper.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is an old Clipper program. I so, there is still active support and even GUI libraries. I suggest you try xharbour. It's not DOS anymore but pure windows based. There is a free version and a pay version (visual xHarbour). With this tool you can even access SQL databases and it's 100% clipper compatible.